# Adding tags to mp3s for use in music players

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, audio, music-player, tagging

I'm hoping this is the correct place to ask.

Basically, I'm using **cmus** and have a little bash script to automate downloading, renaming and moving a mp3.

However, cmus just lists the song name as its full path in the library (e.g.: `/home/user/music/genre/song.mp3`)

I'd like to change this by adding tags such as album, title, and artist to the mp3 files.

I'm not sure if in Unix some files inherently have metadata like this or if you have to create the data in a specific way for the music player to be able to read it.

I read the [cmus man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cmus) and I don't see anything about how it reads tags or labels.

Overall, through a bash script after reading an input, such as '`albumname`' I'd like to know how to assign that input as the album tag of a mp3 file for a music player to use.

Comment: Preferably I would like to completely avoid installing a new program, I was just hoping there's unix commands to modify existing, inherent tags on an mp3

Comment: did you have a look at https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG ?

Comment: I've heard about it, and the wiki only shows installation, I suppose it shows source code too. I'm just wondering if I can look at and change metadata of an mp3 through unix commands alone.

Comment: though if you need command line, I think `id3v2` or `eyeD3` for the command line would be better suited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `eyeD3`.

Install it from **python pip**. pip installs latest version.

Docs here: https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ .

`eyeD3` has good documentation so it's easy to start.

Also it has a bunch of useful plugins - try it!